# How to use lag in R as in Stata

Tags: r, stata, lag

I am trying to recreate a Stata code snippet in **R** and I have hit a snag.

In Stata, the lag function gives this result when applied:

```
A B
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2

replace A=B if A==A[_n-1]

A B
1 2
2 2
1 2
2 2
```

If I try to replicate in **R** I get the following:

```
temp <- data.frame("A" = rep(1,4), "B" = rep(2,4))

temp

 A B
 1 2
 1 2
 1 2
 1 2

temp <- temp %>% mutate(A = ifelse(A==lag(A,1),B,A))

temp

A B
2 2
2 2
2 2
2 2
```

I need it to be the same as in Stata.

Comment: In Stata there is a lag operator (which is not a function). You are using subscripts to access previous values, which is quite different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like we need to update after each run

```
for(i in 2:nrow(temp)) temp$A[i] <- if(temp$A[i] == temp$A[i-1])
            temp$B[i] else temp$A[i]

temp
#  A B
#1 1 2
#2 2 2
#3 1 2
#4 2 2
```

Or as @G.Grothendieck mentioned in the comments, it can be compact with

```
for(i in 2:nrow(temp)) if (temp$A[i] == temp$A[i-1]) temp$A[i] <- temp$B[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

`lag` would not be used here because it uses the original values in `A` whereas at each iteration the question needs the most recently updated values.

Define an `Update` function and apply it using `accumulate2` in the purrr package.  It returns a list so unlist it.

```
library(purrr)

Update <- function(prev, A, B) if (A == prev) B else A
transform(temp, A = unlist(accumulate2(A, B[-1], Update)))
```

giving:

```
  A B
1 1 2
2 2 2
3 1 2
4 2 2
```

Another way to write this uses `fn$` in gsubfn which causes formula arguments to be interpreted as functions.  The function that it builds uses the free variables in the formula as the arguments in the order encountered.

```
library(gsubfn)
library(purrr)

transform(temp, A = unlist(fn$accumulate2(A, B[-1], ~ if (prev == A) B else A)))
```

Also note the comments below this answer for another variation.

Comment: Or using the `..` notation `temp %>% mutate(A = accumulate2(A, B[-1], ~ if(..1 == ..2) ..3 else ..2) %>% flatten_dbl)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will do it:

```
lagger <- function(x,y){
  current = x[1]
  out = x
  for(i in 2:length(x)){
    if(x[i] == current){
      out[i] = y[i]
    }
    current = out[i]
  }
  out
}

lagger(temp$A, temp$B)
[1] 1 2 1 2
```